# First project. Basketball stats book. Lost beginner

Tags: python, statistics

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to create a program that keeps track of:

1. All player names / numbers
2. Shots attempted / made
3. Shot percentage (made/attempted)
4. Total points
5. Fouls
6. Rebounds
7. Assists

I need all of this data to be saved into a file that only pertains to the game that was just played.

Then as more games are added and I have more information, I need another file that adds all of the statistics together. You know what I mean?

I don't even know where to begin. I think I can actually get up to the point where I put all the data in, but how would I export it in a readable format? Remember I have to hand the information to the coach.

Can anyone help me get off on the right foot? Or can any experienced programmer guide me through the whole thing? I'm willing to pay for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data to be human-readable and modifiable, save it as a [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) file:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as handle:
    writer = csv.writer(handle)

    writer.writerow(['Test', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

This won't preserve Python data types, so you'd have to convert the strings back to `int`s and `float`s when you read it back in.

You can also [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) the data, which saves it in an unreadable format that unpickles back into your original Python object, so you can resume working with your original data seamlessly:

```
import pickle

with open('output.pickle', 'w') as handle:
    pickle.dump(['Test', 'foo', 123], handle)
```

Reading the data back in is similar to writing it.

A better approach would be to use a database like MySQL or SQLite to store the data. From there, you can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to query and modify the database easily.

Comment: Man... Can't understand a thing. I've pretty much just started out. Is this too complex of a project for me?

Comment: @dylan: Yeah, probably. I'd try learning the basics of Python first.

Comment: I mean I went through the "Learn Python the Hard Way" book by Zed Shaw. Do you have more resources for me?

Comment: @dylan: I'm afraid not. I learned Python by making things, so I'm not sure what books people use. Are you comfortable with using the documentation to figure out how things work?

Comment: By making things? What sort of things? Like things to help you with your everyday tasks like I'm trying to do? And the documentation? That's the one on python.org, right?

Comment: @dylan: Yeah, more or less. Any sort of documentation you can find on Google.

Comment: Ah. I guess so. I know where to find documentation. It always seems like the more complicated way of finding an answer, though.

Comment: @dylan: What's the less complicated way?

Comment: Stackoverflow :) Or Googling, perhaps.

Comment: @dylan: For the simple stuff, yeah. Usually it's much easier to just look something up in the documentation than to ask a question here and wait for an answer.

Comment: I'll take your word for it since you are much more experienced than I. But every time I ask a question here, I get nearly instant replies. I think I'm just going to start my Python learning from scratch again. How long do you reckon it'll take me to build up the skill set to be able to build the program mentioned in the question?

Comment: @dylan: Personally, I'd just start building your program. It isn't that difficult. It might take a while for you to do, but you will learn a ton more than you'd learn from a basic tutorial.

Comment: Really? Oh boy. It's such a daunting task. I'm excited and scared at the same time, ha.

Comment: @dylan: If you do need serious help with it, I wouldn't mind guiding you through it. My email is in my profile.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot, Blender. I'll be contacting you tomorrow then. I'm about to head to bed.